# SQL - Delete rows if one of the columns has a null value

Tags: sql, null, row

Is there any way to delete all the rows of a table if the value of one of the columns is null, without specifying the particular column?

I am dealing with a table that has a lot of columns, and it is not efficient to specify all of them, so I was wondering if something like this is possible?

Comment: concatenate the columns then delete when null `delete from tableName where concat(id,col1,col2,col3,col4) is null;`  you can use system tables to get you a complete list of all the columns for a table.  [Example](https://rextester.com/FLRNC93387) .  Otherwise how si teh system to know what columns you want to evaluate for a rows deletion?  you have to specify them somewhere.  I suppose you could create  a function based index combining the columns and then delete when null from the function based index...

Comment: @Sapehi . . . "columns" don't have a value.  Rows have values for each column.  Hence, I don't even understand what you are asking for.